# Dynamic update or script equivalent in SQL Server in-memory OLTP (Hekaton)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, in-memory-oltp

I want to write equivalent stored procedure (contain execute string) in natively compiled stored procedure, but I can't find a way to implement that.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are [limited set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/supported-features-for-natively-compiled-t-sql-modules?view=sql-server-2017) of operators that can be used in natively compiled stored procedures.

You are allowed to use [control-of-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/supported-features-for-natively-compiled-t-sql-modules?view=sql-server-2017#cof) language statements like `IF and ELSE`, so this is the closest thing you can get to dynamic execution.